# Using custom fonts in spfx web parts

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, webpack, font

I have a custom web part that displays weather data and I'm using a custom icon font to go along with the data.

It works on the hosted workbench but when I package the solution and deploy it on my tenant, I get the following console errors:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>
OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1702391919
```

The font files are located at `src\webparts\mywebpart\font` and the @font-face and other icon-related styles are in a CSS file `src\webparts\mywebpart\style`.

I added a `copy-static-assets.json` file with the following code:

```
{
    "includeExtensions": [
        "ttf",
        "woff",
        "eot",
        "woff2",
        "svg"
    ]
}
```

My gulpfile was updated to look like this:

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set('serve', result.get('serve-deprecated'));

  return result;
};

// Font loader configuration for webfonts
const fontLoaderConfig = {
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'font/' 
    }
  }]
};

// Merge custom loader to web pack configuration
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {

    generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(fontLoaderConfig);

    return generatedConfiguration;
  }
});

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

And I'm referencing the icon CSS in my MyWebPart.ts file like this:

```
import './style/weather-icons.min.css';
```

In Chrome's inspector, I can see it's referencing the public SharePoint CDN:

[image: sharepoint cdn reference]

And when I click the link, it appears to load the font without issue:

[image: font loading correctly]

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: It's also worth noting that I tried hosting the font files elsewhere too and I get a CORS error.

Comment: How do you know that it is loading the font correctly?
It looks like a something like Times New Roman is being loaded, which may be a fall-back font in the browser.

Comment: @A.k.A Fritz - It’s an icon font so I’m not sure what the standard character set should look like. I assume that if it’s showing me anything at all rather than throwing an error, it loaded. Maybe that’s an assumption I shouldn’t make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) conversion tool to reconvert my files and selected the option to embed files in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the readily accessible Office UI Fabric Icons?
I have never received a CORS error with Fabric UI Icons.

- See UI Fabric Icon Palate here:
  https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/
- Integration into your spfx project here:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration

Comment: Because there aren’t enough weather-related icons to cover every type of weather event.

Comment: Interesting.  How many weather icons does the font you are trying to use have?  How many of those do you expect to actually use?  Is the iconography culture specific?

Comment: I’m not looking directly at it at the moment but it has something like 200 icons. It’s useful to be able to tell the difference between a light rain and a heavy rain, for example. Or high wind. Or a number of other possible events.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.  Glad you were able to fix your issue.  One last question - this is just out of curiosity - what is your data source for the weather in this application?

Comment: I’m using the OpenWeatherMap API. It’s super easy to use but the forecasts (in my hometown at least) so far have been 3-5 degrees (F) different than other forecast I’ve found. I’ll need to match the forecasts up with something authoritative to see how accurate it is before I decide if I stick with it.